# There is no sound card detected while running in Virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, sound, virtualbox, alsa

I have been using Ubuntu 14.04 inside VirtualBox, my host is windows 8.1. Today my sound stopped working inside of the guest. Inside the sound settings there is only a Dummy Output. I went through several steps, including alternating between all three of my possible Audio Controllers and restarting both VB and the Host several times. I tried repairing the AC97 Driver as outlined [here](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/).

There is no ALSA host Audio driver available on the audio settings. After looking into that, I believe that it is the culprit. I have tried to run the alsamixer, but the terminal reported that no file existed. `whereas` found it, and I tried to execute it with a double click in the GUI, but nothing happened. So I Uninstalled and reinstalled the alsa-utils, and the alsamixer several times and the problem still persists.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In a default setup your guest Ubuntu should have all drivers installed needed to use the host sound system for output on a (virtualized) sound device.

When no sound card is detected this usually is an issue with host sound drivers that are not correctly passed through to the Virtual Box sound driver. Re-installing the guest audio system will likely not solve these issues.

To debug this let me suggest the following approaches:

- Open a **guest session** on your virtual Ubuntu to make sure is it not a per-user setting that conflicts with the audio system.
- Boot your VM with identical VM setting from an Ubuntu installation ISO with "Try Ubuntu" to exclude a bad install of the audio system on the already installed Ubuntu.
- Make sure you have the following settings for your virtual machine running on a Windows host:

  - choose **DirectSound** as host audio driver.
  - choose **IHC AC97** as a guest controller.
  - audio should not be muted in the host.
- Update host Virtual Box to the latest release (Windows 10 sound issues were only fixed from release >= 5.0.2).
- Update you guest Ubuntu distribution with latest kernels:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- Check that the guest audio is not muted by running `alsamixer` in a **terminal**.
- If there still is no audio it may help to reinstall the host audio drivers. Host USB audio devices may not work as expected in a virtual machine.

Comment: Running the machine from the ISO had sound, but when installing I had severe problems getting the screen to the correct size and use a Vbox additions ISO. I had to remove that to boot from an ubuntu ISO. So it did have not identical settings. However sound was running with the guest additions yesterday. Updating the kernal did nothing, no changes.

Comment: I got the VM to boot with Ubuntu as the master, and the guest additions as the slave and it had audio. I forgot to mention that a Guest profile does not have sound.